# How can I download mp3 file in Flutter and save it in user device storage?

Tags: file, flutter, audio, save, mp3

I am new in `Flutter`. I want to download an `mp3` file from website and to save in `user device storage`.

When I `save` the `mp3`, later in the app I want to play this `mp3` file.

Can someone give me an example please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

If you are willing to save the file to your application cache folder use:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager

If you want to specify a custom download folder use:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader

To play the mp3 directly through the url without downloading or by passing the file after download use:
https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers